# fish protocol on Macintosh?

Tags: mac

I'm a fan of the fish protocol using konqueror (fish://user@host) on Linux.  Can I set up the same thing on the Mac?  Ideally, having it integrated with the Finder would be great.

Answer (score 2):

OSX includes sftp.
OSX's Terminal  can open SFTP connections, open Terminal and hit cmd-shift-K.
Lets you save ssh, sftp, telnet and ftp sessions.
Not finder integrated.

For a more finder integrated way of using a file system over ssh have a look at http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/ and http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/MACFUSE_FS_SSHFS.

Answer (score 1):

The `fish` thing seems to be using SFTP, so Macfusion might work (configure it for SSH). But not having a Mac, I can't test.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like ExpanDrive (www.expandrive.com/mac), which allows you to mount SFTP connections like other network shares or removable drives. It's commercial software that uses MacFUSE, but has quite a lot of useful improvements over the basic MacFUSE SFTP functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The finder allows you to make (S)FTP sessions.

'Connect to server' allows a range of protocols:

smb://
ftp://
afp://
etc...

I just can't remember which menu it is off the top of my head.

Comment: The menu is go...|connect to server
But in Yosemite, fish and sftp are not recognised protocols.  Works from terminal, but not finder